# Wordpress loading a .txt file and encoding as UTF-8 is not working correctly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, utf-8, encode

I'm loading a txt file and try to display the content in the right format.

With a clean php file it is working correctly but I'm not able to do it inside of wordpress functions.php.

Source from the txt file:
`#Neue und moderne Wohnung N�he Bahnhof#`

First I did a test with a clean php file.

```
<?php
$data_immo = file_get_contents('data/unload.txt');
$objects = explode('IDX3.01#GARAIO REM#', $data_immo);
$output = array_shift($objects); // hidden the first <li>-element

echo '{';
foreach ($objects as $item) {

        $data_details = preg_split ("/\#/", $item);

        $object_title = utf8_encode($data_details[14]);
        $object_title = html_entity_decode($object_title);
        var_dump($object_title)
}
echo '},';
```

Output is correct:
`index.php:18:string 'Neue und moderne Wohnung Nähe Bahnhof' (length=38)`

After that I did the same in Wordpress (functions.php)

Head looks like that:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {{ function('wp_head') }}
</head>
```

But my dump of the $object_title is wrong:
`/api_test/web/app/themes/timber/functions.php:175:string 'Neue und moderne Wohnung Nï¿½he Bahnhof' (length=42)`

So why is Wordpress not able to encode my txt file correctly.

Any help would be great.
Cheers

Comment: First, `{{` is not WordPress, that looks like Twig to me. Are you using Timber? If this is Twig, it is probably getting mangled on disk for caching. Second, once you have UTF-8 you really don't have to worry about `utf8_encode` and `html_entity_decode`, those are probably mangling things, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I use Timber and Twig on my Wordpress Theme. But actually I'm working on the functions.php so It shouldn't be a Twig/Timber problem.

Comment: You might be working in `function.php`, but the second code block along with the `dump` shows that Timber/Twig is still involved. I would try to remove them from the equation completely, just for your own sanity's sake.